# How to Calculate Basic Cycles in MSP430?

Tags: msp430

Hey all I am fairly new with the MSP430 and I have begun using it to do very simple projects and I am trying to keep track of how many cycles I use within my program, and I have a two simple questions that I cannot find the answer for.

How many cycles does it take to run the 'ret' or 'reti' from my program? How many cycles does it take to assign a variable in MSP430 or to call the variable as seen in my "mov.w #COUNT,r13" as seen below?  Here is the part of the code that I am using:

```
COUNT       .equ    <number>                ; <-- Does this take any cycles?    

callLoop:   call    #myDelay                ; 2 cycles
            sub.w   #1,r12                  ; 1 cycles
              jne   callLoop                ; 2 cycles
            jmp     RESET                   ; 2 cycles

myDelay:    mov.w   #COUNT,r13              ; 1  <-- Is it only one cycle to run the mov.w?

delayloop:  sub.w   #1,r13                  ; 1 cycles
              jne   delayloop               ; 2 cycles
            ret                             ; ???  No idea what this would be.
```

r12 has already been assigned a value earlier. Let me know if you need anything else from me.

Comment: Hrm. I was thinking about looking into MSP430, but after a few minutes of researching the answer for this question, I think I'll hold off.

Comment: lol, I feel like there's nowhere for me to find the basic information that I need.  Anything that exists usually assumes that I already know what I'm doing, a pretty hefty assumption.

Comment: Isn't Return simply a jump? But to a memory address held on the stack?

Comment: The answer is actually somewhat convoluted. `ret` is actually `mov.w @sp+,pc` under the hood.

Comment: So if its mov.w @sp+,pc then that means it is going to be 3 cycles because it is indexed and auto-increment from what I understand.  Excellent, where did you find that answer Ignacio?

Comment: http://www.embeddedrelated.com/groups/msp430/show/19028.php

Comment: Superb, one part down. one to go!

Comment: Sounds like 2 to go. But here's one: `.equ` is an assembler directive and generates no instructions.

Comment: I figured if .equ generates no instructions then calling it as my source would also not take an extra cycle, because at that point it is just like calling a constant from r3 or a value from any register, unless I'm mistaken...that's what seems correct to me

Comment: Let me just put it down formally then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/groups/msp430/show/19028.php), `ret` is actually `mov.w @sp+,pc`, so it only takes the cycles required for indirection, post-increment and assignment to the program counter.

`.equ` is an assembler directive similar to `#define` in C and generates no instructions; the `mov.w #,r` uses a constant substituted by the assembler and therefore incurs no additional cycles.